# How do I compile mod_deflate?

Tags: 11.10, apache2, compression

I want to enable compression in apache. For the same I am trying to use deflate module of apache.

I have already installed apache 2. But it is a default installation and in that mod_deflate is not enable. Now I am compiling mod_deflate module by using following commands:

```
cd /usr/local/src/httpd-2.2.21/modules/filters/
/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs -i -c -Wl,lz mod_deflate.c
```

After doing it I have added following line in my httpd.conf file

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

but as soon as i do syntax check I am getting following error
httpd: Syntax error on line 417 of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_deflate.so into server: /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_deflate.so: undefined symbol: inflate

Following is the output of ldd command

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00b2d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00110000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x008e6000)
```

Please help as i dont want to compile apache again.

Comment: Problem has been solved by adding LDFLAGS="-lz" in apr-1-config file.

Comment: Can you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Problem has been solved by adding `LDFLAGS="-lz"` in apr-1-config file.